# Yup' I upgraded my version. How can I use ObjectShape?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

I upgraded the yup version in my react project that I wrote with Typescript.

"yup": "^0.32.11" ->  "yup": "^1.3.2"

[image: Missing file extension for "yup/lib/object"]

I am getting an error like in the image.

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { ObjectShape } from 'yup/lib/object';

type Parameter = ObjectShape & DictionaryLine;


const validations: Yup.SchemaOf<DetailedFormProps> = Yup.object()
  .shape(
    {
      startDate: Yup.date()
        .nullable()
        .when('endDate', {
          is: (endDate: Date) => endDate,
          then: Yup.date()
            .nullable()
            .required('accounts_accountActivities_startDateEndDateSelection_errorMessage'),
          otherwise: Yup.date().notRequired().nullable(),
        })
        .when('endDate', (endDate: Date, schema) =>
          schema
            .test(
              'is-three-months-between-dates',
              'accounts_accountActivities_startDateEndDateRange_errorMessage',
              (startDate?: Date | null) =>
                startDate && endDate ? IsDateDifferenceMoreThanMonths(startDate, endDate, 12) : true
            )
            .max(endDate || new Date(), 'accounts_accountActivities_startDateEndDate_errorMessage')
        )
        .test(
          'is-smaller-than-sysdate',
          'accounts_accountActivities_startdateValidation_errorMessage',
          (startDate?: Date | null) => {
            if (!startDate) return true;

            const NOW_DATE = new Date();
            return startDate.getTime() <= NOW_DATE.getTime();
          }
        ),
      endDate: Yup.date()
        .nullable()
        .test(
          'is-zero',
          'accounts_accountActivities_enddateValidation_errorMessage',
          (endDate?: Date | null): boolean => {
            if (!endDate) return true;

            const NOW_DATE = new Date();
            return endDate.getTime() <= NOW_DATE.getTime();
          }
        )
        .when('startDate', {
          is: (startDate: Date) => startDate,
          then: Yup.date()
            .nullable()
            .required('accounts_accountActivities_startDateEndDateSelection_errorMessage'),
          otherwise: Yup.date().notRequired().nullable(),
        }),
      sort: Yup.object<Parameter>().nullable().notRequired(),
```

How can I use objectShape in the new version so that I can use it here?
yup/lib/object cannot be found in this directory

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no distributed lib folder anymore as everything is bundled into one file with rollup.

You can read all about it [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1906).